# Real-world applications of empty statements as no-op commands in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

As far as I know, JavaScript's *EmptyStatement* statement has two use-cases. It is used:

1. as an no-operation (no-op) command in places where a statement is required, and
2. as a mechanism to ensure that the code is interpreted as intended in scenarios where the programmer omits semicolons from the end of statements (in which case the programmer inserts a semicolon (empty statement) at the beginning of lines that represent new statements but start with a `(`, `[`, `/`, `+`, or `-` token, in order to prevent that line from being interpreted as a continuation of the previous line (statement).)

I would love to see some real-world applications of the first use-case - using empty statements as no-op commands.

I can't remember ever using a semicolon as a no-op command, but if you did, or remember someone else's code that does, could you show how it was used?

Comment: I can't think of a situation in JavaScript in which a statement is required.

Comment: @Pointy Inside compound statements (for, if, while, ...). For instance: `if ( x ) ...` (after the header of an if-statement, a statement is required)

Answer (score 4):

Traverse to the next element node, placing all the logic in the expression evaluated for the `while`.

```
 // ---------empty statement-------------------------------------v
while( node && (node = node.nextSibling) && node.nodeType !== 1 );

// do something with the resulting node
```

Because all the logic (as well as the assignment) is in the expression being evaluated, there's no need for the *Statement*, so an empty one is used.

---

**EDIT:** *Off topic a little.*

These type of `while` statements have sometimes bothered me when reading through a bunch of code quickly.

Perhaps a better form is:

```
do;while( node && (node = node.nextSibling) && node.nodeType !== 1 )
```

...so you can see right at the start that it is using an *EmptyStatement*, though it technically will always require 1 additional processing of the statement.

---

Interestingly, [this jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/empty-while-vs-do-while) consistently gives an ever so slight edge to `do-while` (in Chrome 13 and Firefox 5 anyway). For practical purposes, they are identical.

Comment: Great example. I guess one would put this inside some `getNextElementSibling` function for browsers that don't implement the `nextElementSibling` property.

Comment: Šime Vidas: Yes, `nextElementSibling` and other such properties make this sort of code obsolete. Alas IE6-8 keep it relevant. :o)

Answer (score 3):

I sometimes write code like this:

```
if( somecondition )
  doSomething();
else if( anothercondition )
  doSomethingElse();
else if( thirdcondition )
  ; // we don't need to do anything in this case
else if( fourthcondition )
  goFourthAndMultiply();
else
  panic();
```

Of course, whether one uses `;` or `{}` in these cases is just a stylistic choice.

Comment: But why write `else if( thirdcondition )` if you don't need it. If you don't need it only temporarily, then it would be more appropriate to comment it out...

Comment: Because if thirdcondition is true, then neigher goFourthAndMultiply nor panic() should be done (and the value of fourthcondition does not matter).

Answer (score 0):

One example I can think of, if for some reason you want to convert the following:

```
if(a) {
    if(b) {
       B()
    } else {
       C()
    }
}
```

to use the ternary operator:

```
a ? (b ? B() : C()) : emptystatement;
```

This would be an example of the first case you state.

Comment: No -- the ternary operator requires an _expression_, not a statement.

Comment: But you can still put an expression in there. I was just showing an example where 'something' has to be present.

Comment: @Griffin: But then it's an *ExpressionStatement* instead of an *EmptyStatement*. ;o) http://es5.github.com/#x12.3

Comment: @Griffin If you replace `emptystatement` with some expression, then that entire line represents an expression-statement, and the semicolon is interpreted as the last token of that expression-statement (and not as an empty-statement).

Answer (score 0):

If you create a hyperlink which should not navigate you can do:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="...">Click here</a>
```

This is a bit old-fashioned but it is (or rather was) a use case of it.

Comment: Seeing this, I wonder why others write this: `href="javascript:void(0);"` (as if the `void` expression is required)...

Comment: Maybe because the javascript engine needs a return value? I sometimes write in the event-handler return false;. This can solve big headache.

Comment: Not sure, `javascript:` works equally well. Perhaps compatibility issues with older browsers (this coding style isn't very modern I believe).

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
  some code
} catch(Exception) {;}
```

;

```
for(var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; SomFunction(i++));
```

;

```
if (condition) return; else ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's useful for you ( a C example) :

```
for ( ;; ) {

}
```

or this one:

```
for(var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; SomFunction(i++));
```

Comment: Those two semicolons are not empty statements. They are part of the syntax of the `for` statement.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it looking empty for me.

Comment: That's because the expressions inside `for` headers are optional - [see here](http://es5.github.com/#x12.6.3).

Comment: No, that's because a for-loop would be translated or optimized to a jmp table in opcode.